# How can I check if user id is already registered to the bot? [discord.py]

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a discord bot where only registered user can use the bot. And you can only registered 1 time or the bot will give you an error message. But unfortunately, the bot sends the same result to the registered user. Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import sqlite3 as sl

conn = sl.connect('my-test.db')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='n.')
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (user_ID, gold, level)""")
c = conn.cursor()

@bot.command()
    async def register(ctx):
      GetUserId = ctx.author.id
      c.execute("SELECT user_ID FROM users WHERE user_ID=?", (GetUserId,))
      data = c.fetchall()
      if(GetUserId in data):
          embed = discord.Embed(title="Error!", description="You have been registered to the bot!")
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      else:
          c.execute("INSERT INTO USERS (user_ID) VALUES (?)", (GetUserId,))
          embed = discord.Embed(title="Welcome!", description="some description")
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Can you please help me to fix the issue, cause I've been searching the problem for hours and haven't got the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a list of rows, meaning that it looks something like

```py
[(GetUserId_goes_here,)]
```

You're trying to check if `ctx.author.id` is in this list, but it never is because you're checking if an `int` is in a list of `tuples`, which obviously never matches.

Your `SELECT` will already only choose rows where the `user_ID` matches your given id, so there's no need to check if it's in there or not. Checking if anything at all was returned is enough here: if nothing (empty list) was returned then none of the rows contain `GetUserId`, meaning the user is not yet in your db.

```py
GetUserId = ctx.author.id
c.execute("SELECT user_ID FROM users WHERE user_ID=?", (GetUserId,))
data = c.fetchall()

if not data:
    # Nothing was found, add the user
else:
    # User is already in the database
```

`not data` is the same as `len(data) == 0` in this `if`, because empty lists are `Falsy`. You can use whichever you prefer.

For future reference, if you return all rows in your database and want to check if a user is in there, you should use an `any()` to check if any of the tuples contain this id.

```py
if any(row[0] == GetUserId for row in data):
    # Found at least 1 matching row
else:
    # No matches found
```